# PHP mysqli. ORDER SELECT after one table but SELECT data from another table?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have 2 tables.

**visitors:**

```
pageID
visitorID
last_visit
```

**users:**

```
userID(this ID and the pageID and visitorID in visitors is bundled to the same exact user)
username
age
```

I want to select last 5 visitors of the current logged in user (`ORDER BY last_visit LIMIT 5 in the table visits`)
I want to select the data from table users of those 5 users.(username, age, etc.)

How do i do this?

Comment: How are visitors linked to the user whose pages they visit? Is there a `pages` table that has `userID` and `pageID`?

Comment: No i only have the tables visitors and users.
I take the last numbers(the user_id) from the URL on the userpage and saves it to pageID when a user visits the userpage) I know it aint the best way but thats how i do it :D
The visitorID i get from table users with SESSION when the visitor view the userpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` with a subquery that gets the last 5 visitors.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users AS u
JOIN (SELECT visitorId
      FROM visitors AS v
      WHERE v.pageID = $currentUserID
      ORDER BY last_visit
      LIMIT 5) AS v1
ON u.userID = v1.visitorID
```